# Navigation bar rendering over main container rather than above

Tags: html, css

So I have this navigation which looks good on both mobile and Desktop because it resizes well and accordingly, but I can't get any content after that to go immeadiately below. If I don't set something like padding-top, the navigation is being set over the main_container is being rendered under the navigation bar and hence not being seen.

I would set the padding-top property, but the problem is, this will be a mobile as well as a desktop site. Setting the padding-top property makes the page rendering in mobile very different to desktop. It leaves more padding in mobile than in desktop.

```
<div id="nav_cont">
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php
        $count=0;
        $count++;
        ?>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <?php
        $count++;?>
        <li><a href="register.php">Register a New Store</a></li>
    <?php 
        $count++;?>
        <li><a href="new_mvi.php">Add Movie/Series/Game Titles</a></li>
        <?php
        $count++;?>
        <li><a href="myorders.php">Orders</a></li>
        <?php
        $count++;
        ?>
        <li><a href="editmovies.php?id=<?php echo $storeid;?>">Edit Movie/Series/Game Titles</a></li>
    <?php
        $count++;?>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login to your Store</a></li>
    <?php
        $count++;?>
        <li><a href="cart.php">View Cart</a></li>
    <?php
        $count++;?>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    <?php
        $width=100/($count);
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<style>

#nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    <?php echo "min-width: $width%; width: $width%; max-width: $width%";?>;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#nav_cont{
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    display:table;
}
#nav li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body, div, table, tr, td, a {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#page_container{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#main_container{
    margin: 0px;
}

<div id="main_container">
          <div id="page_container">
                 My Content here <!--This is being rendered under the navigation bar and hence not being seen-->

          </div>
</div>
```

Could you point me to the CSS which I should use to set this right.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use mediaqueries and still use padding.

Comment: I wanted a solution more in line with setting the float or position or something...something that would never break.

Comment: This site should be usable even in old phones with Java browsers and Opera Mini so that's why I want an XHTML/CSS2 solution

Answer (score 1):

Because you set "position: absolute;" on the div with id="nav" you take it out of the normal document flow, in effect making the div with id="main_container" the first element in the document flow and hence positioned at top. Remove "position: absolute;" and main_container will be positioned below nav.

You can also remove "top: 0", "left: 0" and "float: left" as they don't do anything for your layout.